# Sql query to find the holidays in a year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which the columns are year,currency and the third column consist of a string of 100001 and it continues where 1 represents holiday and 0 represents working day in that particular year.
The table I have is like this-

```
Currency      Current year    Date values
Dollar             2017                 100111000 till 365
Rupee            2016                  111000010 till 366
Rupee            2000                  11110011 till 366
```

I need to write a select query which will return the position of all the 1 i.e. the holidays along with date in that particular year.
I want the output of that select query in the format

```
Currency      year     date of holiday
Dollar            2017     01/01/2017
```

Like that it will continue till it lists all the holidays for 2017
Then it will continue for the other years.
I need to write a select statement by connect.

Comment: I'd go with regular calendar table instead, with one row for each date.

Comment: Easiest solution: suppose that you have `1`s at positions 10, 57 and 160 within the bitmap-like (of 365 or 366) digits. If you loop looking for the index of a `1`, you get the offset which is the distance (in days) between January 1st and that particular date. By the way, all the DBMSs I know would support that.

Comment: Am using oracle

Answer (score 1):

Use a numbers table and a complicated `join`:

```
with n as (
      select rownum as n from dual connect by level <= 366
     )
select currency, year,
       (to_date(year || '-01-01') + n.n - 1) as holiday_date
from t join
     n
     on substr(t.datevalues, n.n, 1) = '1';
```